# How to set default values to specific component in Trac?

Tags: trac

I'd like to set the 'Confidential' flag to true as default for a specific component in my Trac system. How can I do this?

I've tried with the `[ticket_custom]` section in `trac.ini`, but I can set the 'Confidential' value as default only for *all* the components. This is not what I want.

Also I was thinking of creating a MySQL query to update all the tickets of my component by hand, and set the `sensitive` value to 1 for the 'Confidential' field. But this is not a clean approach, though.

Thanks!

Comment: May I assume, that you want to set sensitive=1 as default for a specific component only? Your question does not say that clearly, one can only guess from several non-matching phrases, as RjOllos already did.

Comment: @hasienda yes that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: If `sensitive` is the [TicketCustomField](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTicketsCustomFields) name then you must have the following in the `[ticket-custom]` section of trac.ini: `sensitive = checkbox`. That is to assume that `sensitive` isn't just the label for the field. I've modified the answer below to account for that detail.

Answer (score 0):

The [DynamicFieldsPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DynamicFieldsPlugin) supports your use case as of version 1.2.6 (see [[14240]](http://trac-hacks.org/changeset/14240)). You'll need to install from the [0.11](http://trac-hacks.org/svn/dynamicfieldsplugin/0.11/) (not 0.12) branch.

Here is an example:

```
[ticket-custom]
sensitive = checkbox
sensitive.set_to_true_when_component = component2 (overwrite)
```

The checkbox will be toggled to the checked state when *component2* is selected.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... I don't know why. It isn't enabled by default.. acts just as before

Comment: We will need to figure out what is unique about your Trac environment that prevents it from working.  It could be many things, such as a conflict with another plugin. Which Trac version are you running,  and which plugins do you have installed?

Comment: The plugins are (The one where the possible issue is goes first): Sensitive Ticekts, Black_Magic_Ticket_Tweaks, Account Manager, Ticket template, Autocomplete users, Master Tickets, Never Notify Updater. Private tickets, Trac tags, Track spam filter. (I think this all are plugins)

Comment: Which version of Trac are you running?

Comment: To determine if DynamicFieldsPlugin is loading, go to the *New Ticket* page, view the page source (CTRL + U in Firefox or Chrome) and search the page for `/dynfields/dynfields.html`, `/chrome/dynfields/rules.js` and `/chrome/dynfields/layout.js`.

Comment: It is trac 1.0.1. I didn't find anything close to `Dynfields` or Dynamic fields.

Comment: The plugin might not be loading. Assuming it is properly installed and enabled, you should see *plugin loading* messages when the log level is set to `DEBUG` and the webserver or tracd is restarted (see [TracLogging](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLogging) to set the log level). If the plugin is successfully loading, you will see a messages such as: `07:31:48 AM Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading dynfields.rules ...`
`07:31:48 AM Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading dynfields.web_ui ...`. If the plugin is not loading, you may see *Skipping* in the message rather than *Loading*, and possibly a traceback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64749/discussion-between-rjollos-and-aalvz).

Comment: If you'd like to continue debugging, best to continue this over on the Trac [MailingList](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MailingList). You can find me and others there that are familiar with DynamicFieldsPlugin and common problems encountered. Good luck!